# How to automatically insert pragmas in your program

Tags: c, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

I need to write a tool that can take a C code and put **pragmas** on top of some functions. Which compiler framework is the easiest to do such a task. Also if you can provide an example, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What is the properties of those functions that you want to put pragma on top of? You may get different way to do it, ranging from full-blown C parser to bash script.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Normal C functions. I need to insert the pragmas before a function definition. You may assume we are not using K&R style C function definitions.

Comment: I'd write it as a clang plugin possibly

Comment: Do the pragmas need to go inside or outside the function bodies?  Do you format your code systematically?  Do your functions start with a `{` in the left margin?  What happens if a pragma ends up in a structure definition or variable initialization?  If you give appropriate answers to these, you can use simple regexes, possibly even just `sed`.  If you have to analyze the code to determine what to insert and where to insert it, you have far more work to do.  Out of curiosity, why do you need to add pragmas automatically?  How will they benefit you?  And how much code are you retrofitting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this reliably, you need a full C front end, and the ability to modify parsed code.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [C Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html) can probably do what you want.   DMS can parse, build ASTs, and carry out custom transformations on source text, either procedural or as a surface syntax transform.

There are some issues with macros and preprocessor directives; if you parse and retain these, it can do so in many cases but it expandis such directives where they are not "structured".  Retention means you don't get a symbol table.   If you expand all the directives, after parsing you can get a symbol table with the same content that a C compiler produces.

For OP's specific task, he'd like write a source to source transform something like the following:

```
 rule decorate_function_definition_with_pragma(fh:function_head, b: block): declaration -> declaration
       =  " \fh \b " ->
          " \fh 
            #pragma  my_pragma 
            \b "
         if some_condiiton(fh);
```

where "my_pragma" is replace essentially by the pragma text he wants, and some_condition is custom predicate that filters matched function_headers for which the pragma should be inserted.

The pattern matches against the syntax tree, so it cannot mismatch like sed or a regex might.   The secret to this is that the pattern variables reference to grammar rules in the C Front End; a pattern variable of type function_head can only match those trees that the function_head grammar rule(s) can satisfy.

One needs some trivial control logic to run this transformation just once for each encountered function definition.

Comment: ROSE is limited to C/C++ (because it uses EDG) or Fortran (U of Illinois parser).  DMS handles far more languages.   DMS handles source-to-source transformations (e.g., the above); ROSE docs *say* it does but other parts of the ROSE docs say it isn't reliable doing this.  ROSE is implemented largely in C++; DMS is self-implemented using PARLANSE (a parallel programming language) and a set of DSLs.  We seem to both have good flow analyzers for C. DMS's C++ flow analysis is limited to control flow at the moment but we're pushing to dataflow; dunno if Rose does any C++ data flow.

Comment: ... I think ROSE does poorly with processing and retaining comments, because it uses the EDG compiler front end, that throws away comments just as most compiler front ends do. If your intention is to take a C++ program and optimize it before compiling, you may not care about preserving comments.  If your intention is to automate permanent code changes, ROSE can make this hard: how will it retain comments in the resulting code, if it throws them away as it parses?  DMS's goal is to enable automated transformations to code that you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at lex/flex or yacc/bison.

great article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/tutorials/au-lexyacc/index.html

Comment: Ah I know about lex/flex. They are a bit too primitive for my purpose I guess.

Comment: Could you explain your purpose more deeply?

Comment: Look at the question. Just writing a remotely useful C parser is a challenging task, with [f]lex/yacc/bison as with any other toolset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to search for the function definition.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: Regular expressions can't really parse C reliably.

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between regex and C. Regex works on strings. So we can consider the contents of the file as a long string.

Comment: A regular expression cannot parse a context-free language, with the special case of it not being able to find matching parentheses with nested parentheses.  If it can't do that, it can't be used by itself to pick out parts of a C program, which have nested parentheses.