# How can insert pragmas above some functions in my C code

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction, pragma

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to automatically insert pragmas in your program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960974/how-to-automatically-insert-pragmas-in-your-program)

I want a tool to automatically write pragmas on the line above some function definitions. The pragmas are related to some information given by some profiler.

So for example, if I have this function.

```
void some function()
{
....
}
```

After inserting the pragma, it will look something like this,

```
#pragma something
void some function()
{
....
}
```

Now I was thinking, maybe we can use a compilers component to tell us where are all the function definitions (on which lines and columns that is) are, and insert pragmas at the right places. What is the easiest option for me here.

Comment: In the general case this is a more complicated prospect than you seem to think. For example, what happens when you have something like `#if defined FOO void foo(void) #else void foo (int bar) #endif`?