# How can I get the function name as text not string in a macro?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am trying to use a function-like macro to generate an object-like macro name (generically, a symbol).  The following will not work because `__func__` ([C99 6.4.2.2-1](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf#page=64)) puts quotes around the function name.

```
#define MAKE_AN_IDENTIFIER(x) __func__##__##x
```

The desired result of calling `MAKE_AN_IDENTIFIER(NULL_POINTER_PASSED)` would be `MyFunctionName__NULL_POINTER_PASSED`.  There may be other reasons this would not work (such as `__func__` being taken literally and not interpreted, but I could fix that) but my question is **what will provide a predefined macro like `__func__` except without the quotes?**  I believe this is not possible within the C99 standard so valid answers could be references to other preprocessors.

Presently I have simply created my own object-like macro and redefined it manually before each function to be the function name.  Obviously this is a poor and probably unacceptable practice.  I am aware that I could take an existing cpp program or library and modify it to provide this functionality.  **I am hoping there is either a commonly used cpp replacement which provides this or a preprocessor library (prefer Python) which is designed for extensibility so as to allow me to 'configure' it to create the macro I need.**

---

I wrote the above to try to provide a concise and well defined question but it is certainly the Y referred to by @Ruud.  The X is...

I am trying to manage unique values for reporting errors in an embedded system.  The values will be passed as a parameter to a(some) particular function(s).  I have already written a Python program using pycparser to parse my code and identify all symbols being passed to the function(s) of interest.  It generates a `.h` file of `#define`s maintaining the values of previously existing entries, commenting out removed entries (to avoid reusing the value and also allow for reintroduction with the same value), assigning new unique numbers for new identifiers, reporting malformed identifiers, and also reporting multiple use of any given identifier.  This means that I can simply write:

```
void MyFunc(int * p)
{
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        myErrorFunc(MYFUNC_NULL_POINTER_PASSED);
        return;
    }

    // do something actually interesting here
}
```

and the Python program will create the `#define MYFUNC_NULL_POINTER_PASSED 7` (or whatever next available number) for me with all the listed considerations.  I have also written a set of macros that further simplify the above to:

```
#define FUNC MYFUNC
void MyFunc(int * p)
{
    RETURN_ASSERT_NOT_NULL(p);

    // do something actually interesting here
}
```

assuming I provide the `#define FUNC`.  I want to use the function name since that will be constant throughout many changes (as opposed to **LINE**) and will be much easier for someone to transfer the value from the old generated `#define` to the new generated `#define` when the function itself is renamed.  Honestly, I think the only reason I am trying to 'solve' this 'issue' is because I have to work in C rather than C++.  At work we are writing fairly object oriented C and so there is a lot of `NULL` pointer checking and `IsInitialized` checking.  I have two line functions that turn into 30 because of all these basic checks (these macros reduce those lines by a factor of five).  While I do enjoy the challenge of crazy macro development, I much prefer to avoid them.  That said, I dislike repeating myself and hiding the functional code in a pile of error checking even more than I dislike crazy macros.

If you prefer to take a stab at this issue, have at.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such way using the standard C preprocessor, not without passing in the actual name of the function as an argument to the macro. You also have to remember here that `__func__` is not actually part of the preprocessor, it should be treated like a real variable (a character array to be precise).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I understand that this is not possible within the C99 preprocessor and am looking for other possibilities.  I have edited the question to try to make that more clear.

Comment: @altendky - I think the only way is to write your own pre-processor

Comment: It will probably not be possible with other preprocessors either, unless they are specifically tailored to parse and understand the source file, which few are.

Comment: Please explain _why_ you need this; it might help somebody to come up with a totally different approach that you hadn't thought of yourself. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Ruud I try to ask direct and concise questions generally, but I have added the X you requested along with the detailed backstory.  I am at a loss as to why they decided to quote `__func__`.  If they had not then we could easily `#define QUOTE(x) #x`, `#define EXPAND(x) x` and `#define FUNC() QUOTE(EXPAND(__func__))` and end up with both unquoted and quoted function name options.

Comment: @altendky Thanks, your use case makes perfect sense. The simplest solution is of course to pass the string-based function name to `MyErrorFunc`, but that will cost you some memory; I can imagine this is not desirable in an embedded system.

Comment: @Ruud I went back through my particular situation and decided that anything unique is sufficient.  The symbol will be two parts: file/line unique and symptom-descriptive. The descriptive part will be unique within a function and enforced by my symbol-finder program.  The non-source file with the file, function, descriptive part, and value will be generated and revisioned and may be tweaked by developers (retain value consistency when renaming a function, etc).  Only the header will contain the file/line unique part and it will not be revision controlled or tweaked by developers.

Answer (score 1):

`__FUNCTION__` *used* to compile to a string literal (I think in **gcc 2.96**), but it hasn't for many years. Now instead we have `__func__`, which compiles to a string *array*, and `__FUNCTION__` is a deprecated alias for it. (The change was a bit painful.)

But in *neither* case was it possible to use this predefined macro to generate a valid C identifier (i.e. "remove the quotes").

But could you instead use the *line number* rather than function name as part of your identifier?

If so, the following would work. As an example, compiling the following 5-line source file:

```
 #define CONCAT_TOKENS4(a,b,c,d)      a##b##c##d
 #define EXPAND_THEN_CONCAT4(a,b,c,d) CONCAT_TOKENS4(a,b,c,d)
 #define MAKE_AN_IDENTIFIER(x)        EXPAND_THEN_CONCAT4(line_,__LINE__,__,x)

 static int MAKE_AN_IDENTIFIER(NULL_POINTER_PASSED);
```

will generate the warning:

> foo.c:5: warning: 'line_5__NULL_POINTER_PASSED' defined but not used

Comment: I am trying to maintain consistency of the actual values through the development and having line numbers changing all the time would make that much more difficult.  Thanks for taking the time to give this a shot.

Comment: See my detailed comment against the question itself, but yes, I can use the line number as you suggest.  It simply requires two separate files to be generated.  Two files when manually maintaining would be terrible, but as I would be generating them it is just fine.  Thanks for helping me get to my solution that bypasses the question.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by others, there is no macro that returns the (unquoted) function name (mainly because the C preprocessor has insufficient syntactic knowledge to recognize functions). You would have to explicitly define such a macro yourself, as you already did yourself:

```
#define FUNC MYFUNC
```

To avoid having to do this manually, you could write your own preprocessor to add the macro definition automatically. A similar question is this: [How to automatically insert pragmas in your program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960974/how-to-automatically-insert-pragmas-in-your-program)

If your source code has a consistent coding style (particularly indentation), then a simple line-based filter (sed, awk, perl) might do. In its most naive form: every function starts with a line that does not start with a hash or whitespace, and ends with a closing parenthesis or a comma. With **awk**:

```
{
    print $0;
}

/^[^# \t].*[,\)][ \t]*$/ {
    sub(/\(.*$/, "");
    sub(/^.*[ \t]/, "");
    print "#define FUNC " toupper($0);
}
```

For a more robust solution, you need a compiler framework like [ROSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROSE_(compiler_framework)).

Comment: I think it is finally settling in.  It is not the preprocessor which expands __func__ to "MyFunc" but rather the preprocessor simply ignores __func__ and lets the compiler itself treat it as an actual C symbol...  ROSE certainly looks to be a good thing for me to be aware of on this topic.  Thanks for pointing it out.  Ditto on the pragma insertion question.

Answer (score 0):

Gnu-C has a `__FUNCTION__` macro, but sadly even that cannot be used in the way you are asking.

Comment: This should be a comment at most.

Comment: I appreciate the response but 'there is something that does not do what you want' does not answer a question which is specifically not constrained to cpp.